# Configure COM port with CRT functions

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, crt

Is it possible to configure a COM port (bitrate, parity) on Windows using only CRT functions? Or must I use Win32 functions (`CreateFile, SetCommState, ReadFile, WriteFile`), to use it with the bitrate and parity I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "CRT" you mean "standard C functions", then I would not expect it to be possible, no.

Serial ports are not something covered by the C language, so their configuration and management must be system-specific.

In Linux, it's the [`termios` POSIX API](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) that you use for this, but as clarified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933745/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-to-the-capabilities-defined-in-sys-select-h-and-t) it's not available in Windows.

Comment: By "CRT", I mean the one from Visual C++, which contains standard C90 functions + some ersatz of POSIX functions + some Microsoft extensions.

Comment: I just confirmed that there is no reference to `SetCommState()` whatsoever in the CRT source code, so I'll accept your answer.