# asciinema missing files: ImportError: No module named 'termios'

Tags: python, pip

When running `asciinema rec`, `asciinema.exe` both from inside `C:\Python34\Scripts` which is the only place the `pip` command works in git bash.

```
$ asciinema.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\Scripts\asciinema-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('asciinema==0.9.8', 'console_scripts', 'asciinema')()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry
_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entr
y_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\asciinema\__main__.py", line 4, in <module
>
    from .commands.builder import get_command
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\asciinema\commands\builder.py", line 4, in
 <module>
    from .record import RecordCommand
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\asciinema\commands\record.py", line 4, in
<module>
    from asciinema.recorder import Recorder
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\asciinema\recorder.py", line 5, in <module
>
    from .pty_recorder import PtyRecorder
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\asciinema\pty_recorder.py", line 2, in <mo
dule>
    import pty
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pty.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tty
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ImportError: No module named 'termios'
```

Comment: I faced the same problem, I install asciinema in my MSYS2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not supported as it doesn't have pseudo-terminal, `select()` and other unix capabilities. Installing Cygwin won't help either as it doesn't support UNIX-like pseudo-terminal as well.

<sup>Source: [Windows not supported](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/issues/47#issuecomment-29236223) at [GH-47](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/issues/47) & [GH-150](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/issues/150)</sup>

See also: [What is the Windows equivalent to the capabilities defined in sys/select.h and termios.h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933745/55075)

---

#### Workarounds

- You may try [`mattn/asciinema`](https://github.com/mattn/asciinema/tree/windows) fork (`windows` branch).
- Run it within a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/asciinema/asciinema/).
- Install `asciinema` in [Bash terminal in Ubuntu for Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0)

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows world, termios is available via Cygwin because of the POSIX specification.

Mingw32 does not support termios.

(I've a similar issue with urwid, which depends on termios, too)

Comment: So just installing `cygwin` solves this? I ran into this trying to use `django-mysql` package

Comment: I installed Cygwin but the problem still remains.