# Get a string without displaying it on the console

Tags: c, graphics

I want to get a string (with space) from user but I don't want it to display on the console. Is there any way in the C language that makes it possible?

Comment: Not in standard C. For all you know, there might not even be a console.

Comment: Maybe have a look at (n)curses, or give the platforms, where your program should run.

Comment: The closest you'll get to anything standard is `getpass`. See this question on possible alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196418/getting-a-password-in-c-without-using-getpass-3

Comment: [graphics] seems a rather inappropriate tag here. Found nothing related to console input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own version of `getch` like so, and mask it. The following example spits out the input just for logging/testing purposes. You can disable that by removing the `printf` calls.

Good luck!

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int getch();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int ch;
   printf("Press x to exit.\n\n");
   for (;;) {
      ch = getch();
      printf("ch = %c (%d)\n", ch, ch);
      if(ch == 'x')
         break;
   }
   return 0;
}

int getch() {
   struct termios oldtc;
   struct termios newtc;
   int ch;
   tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldtc);
   newtc = oldtc;
   newtc.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
   tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newtc);
   ch=getchar();
   tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldtc);
   return ch;
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
gcc test.c  && ./a.out


Press x to exit.

ch = a (97)
ch = b (98)
ch = c (99)
ch = 1 (49)
ch = 2 (50)
ch = 3 (51)
ch =
 (10)
ch =
 (10)
ch = x (120)
```

**References**

---

1. *Hide password input on terminal*, Accessed 2014-07-18, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to disable *echoing* characters typed by user. You can do that by setting the terminal attributes using functions from `<termios.h>` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 512

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* get terminal attributes */
   struct termios termios;
   tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &termios);

   /* disable echo */
   termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &termios);

   /* read a line */
   char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = { 0 };
   fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

   /* enable echo */
   termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &termios);


   /* print the line */
   printf("line: %s", line);

   return 0;
}
```

The example above reads one line (without echoing the characters back) and then it just prints the line back to the terminal.

Comment: Is it using header files of Visual c?

Comment: Sorry, but it is for a Unix environment. The C language is rare for Windows at these days, so I thought you have a Linux environment or something similar. Windows doesn't have <termios.h> (at least), perhaps you may find an equivalent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933745/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-to-the-capabilities-defined-in-sys-select-h-and-t

Comment: For me, the terminal remains unwilling to echo after -reenabling echo.

Comment: it works properly if the original termios is stored and restored. This requires two termios structs. Your version fails to display my text afterward.